# Lightbox2: How do I add an "EDIT" <a> between the "lb-prev" and "lb-next" divisions?

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox2

I am using lightbox2 from "http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/".  I have everything working as desired but I want to add an "EDIT" capability so I can open a page that will allow me to add data via IPTC into the jpg image file.  I tried to put an "`<a>`" between the "lb-prev" and "lb-next" anchors in the .js file and I modified the .css file to include an "lb-edit" and adjusted the widths but when the image displays, the "lb-next" is UNDER the container.  The css for "lb-prev" has "float:left" and the css for "lb-next" has "float:right" but if I put something in the middle, the "lb-next" falls off.  I tried "display:inline" to no avail.  Thanks.  Fragments follow:

lightbox.js has:

```
`<div class="lb-nav"><a class="lb-prev" href="" ></a><a class="lb-edit" href=""></a><a class="lb-next" href="" ></a></div>`
```

...and...

```
this.$lightbox.find('.lb-edit').on('click',function() {

  window.location.href="../../lb-edit.php"

});
```

lightbox.css has:

```
.lb-prev, .lb-edit,.lb-next {
height: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
}

`.lb-nav a.lb-prev {
 width: 33%;
 left: 0;
 float: left;
 background: url(../images/prev.png) left 48% no-repeat;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
 transition: opacity 0.6s;
 }

 .lb-nav a.lb-prev:hover {
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
 opacity: 1;
 }
 .lb-nav a.lb-edit {
 width: 34%;
 left: 0;
 margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;
 background: url(../images/edit.png) left 48% no-repeat;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
 transition: opacity 0.6s;
 }
.lb-nav a.lb-edit:hover {
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
 opacity: 1;
 }  
 .lb-nav a.lb-next {
 display:inline;
 width: 33%;
 right: 0;
 float: right;
 background: url(../images/next.png) right 48% no-repeat;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
 transition: opacity 0.6s;
 }

 .lb-nav a.lb-next:hover {
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
 opacity: 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Close this... I changed the order of the lb-prev, lb-next and lb-edit such that the two "end" pieces were rendered first then the "edit" part fit into the middle.  God, but I love this stuff!!!